# Does anybody know a software that checks simple rules of indentation

Tags: c, programming-languages

By simple rules I mean, tabs after if, for and while's, the use of { }, the basic indentation to organize source codes.

I am looking particularly for C, but it doesn't need to be specific to a programming language, in fact, if it is general, it is better.

Thank you.

Comment: vim (just highlight the text in visual mode and hit equals)

Comment: I use [Astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) and love it. Its formatting ruleset has a good number of options and works well.

Comment: if you only want to *check*, then fix the indentation with a tool then do a compare/diff.

Comment: Actually, I need to check automatically in a database of source codes the ones that are well indented, and see something like how many times they broke the "rules".

Comment: In eclipse with ctrl-shift-f makes the identation in many languages.

Answer (score 1):

try Astyle and uncrustify.

Consider using a temporary file as output and check whether there are differences between the two of them.